# Show $\frac{\sin(x)\cos^{n}(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\sim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x}{\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> Show $$\dfrac{\sin(x)\cos^{n}(x)}{1-\cos(x)}\sim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{x}{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
>   by strating from the left side and get the right side i don't want to use

$$f\sim g \iff \dfrac{f}{g}\underset{}{\overset{}{\longrightarrow}} 0$$

My thoughts:

$$\sin(x)\sim_{x\to 0}x$$
$$1-\cos(x)\sim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^2}{2} $$

how can i apply this since there is $\cos^{n}(x)$ i know it's $\cos^{n}(x)\leq 1$

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Your thoughts are correct.

Comment: how can i apply this since there is $\cos^{n}(x)$ i know it's $\cos^{n}(x)\leq 1$

Comment: Well $\cos^n(x) \sim_{x \to 0} 1$